# Usng jquery need to create division sums without remainders

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my current project, I am creating random mathematics questionnaires for abacus student. So the exam page will serve sums one by one. Based on the student level I am generationg sums at front end using jquery and rendering to get student answer for validation. In a particular level I need to generate divisions with zero remainder.

So, I am using below function to generate the sum which is returning undefined sometimes.

```
    tripleDigitSingleDigitWithoutRemainder: function()
    {
        var dividend = BOBASSESSMENT.general.randomIntFromInterval(100, 999);
        var divisor = BOBASSESSMENT.general.randomIntFromInterval(2, 9);
        console.log("out: " + dividend + "_" + divisor);
        console.log("remainder: " + (dividend % divisor));
        var result_val = "";

        // result_val  = dividend % divisor;


        if(dividend % divisor != 0)
        {
            console.log('loop_again');
            BOBASSESSMENT.general.tripleDigitSingleDigitWithoutRemainder();
        }else{
            result_val = dividend + "_" + divisor;
            console.log("return: " + result_val);
        }
        console.log("final_return: " + result_val);
        return result_val;

    }
```

hence, please help me here to do further.

the requirement is to show question one by one and  I need a dividend value and divisor value which does give remainder as 0. It means 16 % 2 = 0 not like 16 % 3 = 1.

Can you please some one help here.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to generate the divisor and answer, i.e. 8 and 2 in your example, then multiply them together to get the first number 16? Then you know 16 / 2 has no remainder because you constructed it that way.

Comment: As to your existing code, you're calling tripleDigitSingleDigitWithoutRemainder recursively to try again but then discarding the result you get from that. Save the result from the recursion, i.e. `result_val = BOBASSESSMENT.general.tripleDigitSingleDigitWithoutRemainder();` But it would be clearer to me to do this with a loop in the function that repeats when you didn't get a valid result rather than recursion.

Comment: Thans Rup for your mediate response. Yes, we can generate like this. But, in some we have rules like the dividend should be 3 digits or 2 digit like that. For that I am creating the dividend first.

Comment: Thanks you @Rup. yes I got it now. it resolved while assigning the function to 'result_val' variable. Thanks again.

Comment: If possible, please give me an example of using loop instead of recursion.

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comments. Isn't it better to just create a working division by creating it with a product?

```js
function generate() {
  // Numbers [2-9]
  var small = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 2

  // This will give the limit of current divider
  var limit = Math.ceil(900 / small)
  
  // We check the minimum now
  var minimum = Math.floor(100 / small)

  // We create a new random with given limit
  var big = Math.ceil(Math.random() * limit) + minimum

  // Create the product
  var product = big * small;

  return { question: product + ' / ' + small, answer: big }

}

console.log(generate())
```

Answer (score 2):

As discussed in the comments here's a way to use a loop to try again with different values instead of recursion:

```
tripleDigitSingleDigitWithoutRemainder: function()
{
    for(;;)
    {
        var dividend = BOBASSESSMENT.general.randomIntFromInterval(100, 999);
        var divisor = BOBASSESSMENT.general.randomIntFromInterval(2, 9);

        if(dividend % divisor == 0)
        {
            var result_val = dividend + "_" + divisor;
            console.log("return: " + result_val);
            return result_val;
        }
    }
}
```

Here we have an infinite loop and we keep looping until we have a valid problem and then immediately return when we do. `for(;;)` is one way of writing an infinite loop: there are others e.g. `while (true) { ... }` if that's clearer - up to you.

(However I prefer the approach in Wimanicesir's answer which constructs a correct value rather than just trying repeatedly until we find one, which may take many more goes.)

Comment: Good loop example, however still want to remark that my answer (that is based on your comment suggestion) will be faster to generate as it doesn't generate false answers.